# How to set tm_hour python (time module)

Tags: python

I am trying to subtract two dates without the time. When I try to set the hour, min, and second to 0, I get the error `AttributeError: readonly attribute`. Is there any way to set the hour min and second to 0?

```
first_date = datetime_object.date().timetuple()
current_date.tm_hour = 0
current_date.tm_min = 0
current_date.tm_sec = 0
print('current_date', current_date, 'tyeeeee', type(current_date))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to set hour, minute and second to zero. As they are zero by default, following `datetime` library documentation:

> date.timetuple: Return a time.struct_time such as returned by time.localtime(). The hours, minutes and seconds are 0, and the DST flag is -1. d.timetuple() is equivalent to:

```
time.struct_time((d.year, d.month, d.day, 0, 0, 0, d.weekday(), yday, -1))
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects

Answer (score 0):

Simply make both the dates of type: `datetime`.
Then subtract

```
diff=second_date - first_date
difference_in_days = diff.days
```

`difference_in_days` will give you the number of days in `int` type.